# Export MySQL tables to Oracle DB

Tags: mysql, oracle

I would like to migrate my existing mysql db (ver 5) to Oracle DB (11g).

The export scripts provided by phpmyadmin do not seem to work.

Comment: if you could describe your problem in a little more detail please.

Comment: The question is perfectly clear for someone who had the same problem. My solution was `mysqldump --compatible=oracle --complete-insert --compact --default-character-set=latin1 --no-create-info --no-create-db --extended-insert=0 --skip-quote-names` and it works, but it is not perfect, because a few special strings aren't quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to this in Oracle Help it self. They have a topic on [migrating third party databases](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/mysql-093223.html), but an easier method is to export your data as .csv files and then import them into oracle.

Comment: can you please provide the link to that help document

Answer (score 1):

http://www.packtpub.com/article/migrating-mysql-table-using-oracle-sql-developer-1.5

hope helps you